# Block a specific random folder

Tags: c++

I was creating a program that would block certain folders in a directory, only I'm having a problem with a folder that creates a random name such as:

EX:
"FOLDER_201798267374"
"FOLDER_201784736272"

Is not there a way to say that all folders starting with FOLDER_ * should be blocked?

so it does not seem to work.

```
int allow =
        !strncmp(blockfolder, "FOLDER_", 7) ||
        ;
```

Comment: Your code looks like C++. Why did you tag it C# as well ? is that a mistake ?

Comment: yes, I'm new ... I was wrong to tag.

Comment: no problem. I removed the c# tag, then.

Comment: `strncmp` return `0` on match, so remove the `!`

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `StartsWith` method as below:

```
string strTemp = "FOLDER_201784736272";
if (strTemp.StartsWith("FOLDER_")) //returns True if string starts with FOLDER_
{
 //your logic
}
```

Comment: the question was retagged, `StartsWith` is not part of `std::string`